# Negative Easting while converting long/lat to UTM zone

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, latitude-longitude, utm

I have a dataset of some points in python which have longitude and latitude for each of them. Because they are located in different UTM zones, when I want to convert them to UTM, I will get some negative Easting points. Is there any function in python/QGIS or everywhere that will be smart enough to solve this problem?

Comment: This is an expected result to get negative value if the point is in east of the target UTM zone.  What is wrong here?

Comment: Since UTM zones are strictly bounded by declared longitude values, surely you can create a filter to only process those that are in a specified UTM zone. As @KadirŞahbaz says, the negative values are correctly converted, they are just not in that UTM zone.

Answer (score 1):

Yes!  use the UTM Python Library.
From the command line install utm

```
pip install utm
```

Then try something like:

```
import utm
utm.from_latlon(48, -122)
(574595.1124862543, 5316784.0095401555, 10, 'U')
utm.from_latlon(-48, -122)
(574595.1124862543, 4683215.9904598445, 10, 'G')
```

Where 'U' = is a particular latitude band within UTM zone North  and 'G' = is a latitude band within UTM zone South